# Getting a Turtle to move to a random position (within a time interval, e.g. 15 ticks), then search for turtles/objects at that position (45 ticks)

Tags: netlogo

I want to create two types of turtles (1. could be an object):

1. Turtles who doesn't move (could be an object instead of turtle?), but is randomly placed at the bottom of the screen or at the top of the screen.
2. Turtles which goes through two phases then ***repeats***;

   - firstly it ***searches*** the area within a time interval, e.g. 45 ticks, then
   - it ***moves*** to a random position within a time interval, e.g. 15 ticks.

Within the **searching phase**

- If the moving turtle is near (in-radius 5) a turtle/object that does not move, then it should move towards the turtle/object and 'investigate' for 15 ticks.

---

I have only gotten the turtles to stop at a patch of red whenever it is on the patch, but i would like to expand to what i have described above. How do i do it?